# curl function and multipart/form-data issue

Tags: php, curl, multipartform-data

does curl function need any special option to post multipart/form-data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [curl_setopt()](https://www.php.net/curl-setopt) to set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to an **associative array**.

Answer (score 1):

Use curl's -F (or --form) and --form-string options to POST multipart/form-data.

That is, assuming you are talking about the curl program, not the libcurl library. This wasn't clear from your question.